# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not expanding in .net webforms application

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu, dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5

**The nav bar dropdown is not working or expanding when i am clicking it. Im utilizing bootstrap 5.2.3 in NuGet package. I want it to work.It is just not showing the dropdown menu when i am pressing it**
Is it because the bootstrap is not targeting the menu?
I need help with this

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="EmployeeManagementSystem.SiteMaster" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="/content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ewfXo9Gq53e1q1+WDTjaHAGZ8UvCWq0eXONhwDuIoaH8xz2r96uoAYaQCm1oQhnBfRXrvJztNXFsTloJfgbL5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8cac405d2.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Employee Management System</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="basicFormsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Basic Forms
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="basicFormsDropdown">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/Employee">Employee</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/Department">Department</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/Address">Address</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/Role">Role</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/Job">Job</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/JobHistory">Job History</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/VotingRecord">Voting Record</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Pages/EOM">EOM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```